# Getting the frame pkt_pts from ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I record a stream similar to this (but I pipe the image to stdout and process the frames in real time):

```
ffmpeg -debug_ts -y -i http://my_stream.com -strict -2 out.mp4
```

Now I need to map my frames to the **pkt_pts**. This **pkt_pts** I can get by running:

```
ffprobe -i http://my_stream.com -show_frames -select_streams v:0
```

Although starting ffprobe is not an option since I need to excactly know which **pkt_pts** belongs to what frame.
Therefore I'm using the -debug_ts in my ffmpeg call, which gives me a lot of output to stderr, which I then parse out. The only output line which matches the number of frames is the one which starts with: `muxer <- type:video` This line does contain a **pkt_pts**, but it always starts with 0 (not the global **pkt_pts**).

Is there a way to map a frame, to the global **pkt_pts** in real time with ffmpeg?

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by `global pkt_pts`?

Comment: Yes.
So basically what I call global pkt_pts is the pkt_pts which is set by the stream source (and typically does not start on 0 when I start the recording).

My goal is that if I start 2 recordings with ffmpeg I could use this pkt_pts as a unique frame identifier (as far as I know the pkt_pts restarts from 0 after 26.5h, so it is not unique but coupled with the recording time it would get unique).

Is there a way to get such a frame identifier?

Comment: Add `-vsync 0` or `-copyts` before `-i`. Try with the former first.

Comment: I did some experiments:
-vsync 0 resulted in pkt_pts starting on a value around 11'000 if I restarted the recording after a few seconds it started again on a similar value. And it is not the pkt_pts I receive with ffprobe.

With -copyts the video is not record the video properly (it can't be played with vlc) and I got no 'muxer <- type:video' lines on stderr

Did I forget something?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your original command, and extract lines starting with

`demuxer -> ist_index:X`

where `X` is the index number of the stream you want.

In each line, e.g.

```
demuxer -> ist_index:12 type:video next_dts:10851838034 next_dts_time:10851.8 next_pts:10851705034 next_pts_time:10851.7 pkt_pts:976665480 pkt_pts_time:10851.8 pkt_dts:976665480 pkt_dts_time:10851.8 off:0 off_time:0
```

`-pkt_pts` divided by stream timebase, `90000` for TS input, will give you full precision `pkt_pts_time`. If you don't know the timebase, see the input dump for your stream

```
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 768x432, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
```

and use the `tbn` value.

Be aware that your ffprobe command selects the first video stream, but your ffmpeg command leaves it to ffmpeg to select streams, which may not select the same streams.

Comment: I'm afraid this will not do the trick... 
`demuxer -> ist_index:0` is only outputted 1595 times for a 3000 (in one experiment I performed) frame video.

I do not necessarily need the pkt_pts_time I just need an identifier... If pkt_pts works as an identifier, pkt_pts/90000 would as well. BTW: pkt_pts_time is actually already a field in the `demuxer -> ist_index` line.

Any other ideas?

Comment: a) how did you check there are 3000 input frames? b) the MP4 muxer will duplicate frames to maintain CFR. So multiple output frames may have the same input PTS.

Comment: `pkt_pts_time` is displayed with 1 mantissa digit so multiple input packets can show same value.

Comment: a) I did iterate over the frames with cv2 and counting the frames.
b) Ah ok that is interesting...